# Blurry charts and rotated text in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, charts, report, builder, blurry

I am having a heck of a time trying to fix the output of SSRS to look good when it renders in IE of all things.  It looks nice and crisp in FireFox and Report Builder 3, but it just gets trashed inside IE (all running on Win 7).

Most of my users use IE, and the versioning of IE is controlled by corporate, so I don't have the option of pushing out a new version to try.

I've seen hints in my research that the resolution can be tweeked (though I never quite understood *where* to do so) but now that I see that it is nice in FireFox (except that I lose my 270 degree text rotation), I have to think that SSRS is doing its job.

I should add that the rotated text looks good when exported to Excel, but the chart is still blurry (would love to fix that at the very least since I suspect that will be the vehicle most people use to view this report).

Any suggestions?

Thank you for looking!

Jason

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would potentially think it could be the font type you are using off the top of my head.  It is VERY hard to get SSRS to play the exact same on IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc... across different browser versions.  Keep in mind that SSRS, to my knowledge, renders things in the RDL file's XML and that on top of that a browser can provide it's own interpretation of the casting of the presentation.  The easiest thing I have found rather than spending time on a complex solution is re tweak your code to use different font types.  Tahoma at times plays nice with other browsers, but I am not certain as every person's situation is different.

With the rotation I would suspect that IE is using some type of proprietary rendering through Active X or similar.  There have been some complex work around's but honestly if your corporate policy allows it I would just install 'IE Tab' for Chrome and Firefox users as it mimics the imaging of the IE engine.

It is a VERY hard task IMHO to make things look close to identical on all browsers, especially when you are wanting to do that for a proprietary technology by a company that has more vested interest in one browser over the others.  I have had cases where people would tell me that Chrome and Firefox did not work for certain reports in the past due to the way they rendered.  I told them I could only account for IE.

Another thing to think about is that you may generate your own HTML form and present SSRS directly from calling the service.  You basically create an HTML page, have a form, link to the SSRS server and call it.

Comment: Tahoma actually looks much better in Word rendering also... at least versus Calibri.  thx for that suggestion.